# NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler, spring-aop

I understand similar question has been asked before but I've tried all those solutions but nothing has worked for me.
I'm getting the following error. I've added spring-aop and excluded it from jersey-spring
All the code is on GITHUB:
https://github.com/yogi-oc/OC-Latest-Spring

Using Java 8 and Tomcat 8
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
Jun 23, 2016 10:24:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapAuthenticationProvider' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [org/akaza/openclinica/applicationContext-core-security.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator#2f6a096c' of type [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator#2f6a096c' defined in class path resource [org/akaza/openclinica/applicationContext-core-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'openClinicaLdapUserSearch' while setting bean property 'userSearch'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openClinicaLdapUserSearch': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.akaza.openclinica.service.user.LdapUserService org.akaza.openclinica.service.user.OpenClinicaLdapUserSearch.ldapUserService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] for bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' defined in null: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.akaza.openclinica.dao.core.OCContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(OCContextLoaderListener.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
```

And another thing

Bean creation error for `"org.springframework.security.filterChains"` comes when you are using spring version higher than 3.1 and have not added dependencies manually for `spring-aop, spring-jdbc, spring-tx and spring-expressions` in you `POM.xml`.

Reason : If don't do so, maven automatically downloads older version jars (3.0.x) for these artifacts which conflict with newer version spring security jars.

Credit goes to [@aayushdriger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2814068/aayushdriger)

Answer (score 0):

When I looked in the web/target folder, under the exploded war there were no jars. I removed the entire folder and reran Tomcat within intelliJ and this time around it did explode the war with all the jars. The application is running successfully.

Comment: Always check your exploded war folder.